# Binding by ElementName in Resources failing when being used with DynamicResource but works with StaticResource

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, staticresource

In a WPF UserControl I'm binding the `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` in the Resources portion to a dependency property on the UserControl.
If I use the `SolidColorBrush` with a `StaticResource` everything works fine, however if I try using `DynamicResource` the binding fails with an error. While I can work around the issue by using at least one StaticResource to refer to the `SolidColorBrush` I want to know why it's behaving this way to improve my understanding of WPF.

Here's the UserControl xaml, codebehind, and error...

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestUserControl"
                x:Name="MyUserControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushKey" Color="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl,Path=TestProp}"></SolidColorBrush>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="{DynamicResource BrushKey}">Foo</TextBlock>
        <!-- Uncommenting this makes everything work, including the DynamicResource reference. -->
        <!--<TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BrushKey}">Bar</TextBlock>-->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```vb
Public Class TestUserControl

    Public Property TestProp As Color
        Get
            Return GetValue(TestPropProperty)
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            SetValue(TestPropProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly TestPropProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestProp",
                                                                                                GetType(Color),
                                                                                                GetType(TestUserControl),
                                                                                                New PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(&H0, &HBC, &HC4)))

End Class
```

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyUserControl'. BindingExpression:Path=TestProp; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=29677729); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you running against?  It works just fine for me on .NET 4.5 with only the `DynamicResource`.  Do you get different results if you replace `ElementName=MyUserControl` with `Source={x:Reference MyUserControl}`?

Comment: It was originally done in .NET 3.5, but I get the same error when I change the project to .NET 4.0 and 4.5. Replacing `ElementName=MyUserControl` with `Source={x:Reference MyUserControl}` works. Visual Studio 2013 says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for the whole `Color` property in the designer, but it compiles and runs fine, odd.

Comment: Unfortunately, `x:Reference` does not work in the designer, but it does work at runtime.

Comment: The XAML editor has many bugs, it's just normal to hear something like that. Also I've just tried a simple demo (bind to some property of Window, instead of UserControl) and it works with just DynamicResource. (.net 4.5).

Comment: I also can confirm that it works fine if you're in a `Window` instead of a `UserControl`, unfortunately it doesn't work in a `UserControl` and I'm wanting to find out why.